# Javascript slice() seems slow

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

So, I'm not doing anything too complex.  I'm slicing out a dataset from a larger dataset for the purpose of displaying this dataset onto a smaller table on the browser.  My source data is about 50 objects in an array, and the table will show ten at once (controlled by a slider).

I'm new to javascript and decided to "oopify" my project, and once I did that things seemed to slow right down.  I put a time stamp on the function that does the slicing and it's taking between 20-80ms to do the slice.  Is this a normal issue with slice?  I'm pretty sure I've isolated the bottleneck.

```
var start = 1; //controlled by slider
var records = 10; //how many records to slice
updateView = function() {
  dataset.viewData = dataset.sourceData.slice(start, start+records));
}
```

Of course the dataset.sourceData is an array of objects, something like this:

```
[
  {
  "Name": "Bob",
  "Age": "32
  },
  {
  etc...
  }
];
```

I'm pretty sure my object is fine, it simply defines the variables like sourceData and viewData in the constructor.

I figure I should nip this performance issue in the butt sooner than later since if it's choking on only 50 entries, what will happen when I multiply the load...!!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a demo demonstrating this behavior? Did you calculate the delay using imprecise date objects, or with `performance.now()`?

Comment: FYI, `.slice()` makes a new array and copies the items from the original array over to the new array.  In your case since the array elements are objects, it's just going to put a reference to the same object in the new array so the objects themselves are not copied.

Comment: Could you tell us how you measured this? I just did a similar test via JsPerf and I managed to 10.000.000 operations per second. So, I'm guessing you're either not measuring the bottleneck, or you're measuring incorrectly: http://jsperf.com/js-slice-measure

Comment: Found your problem. The phrase is "nip it in the bud". Try changing "butt" to "bud" and give it a go.

Comment: @jfriend, interesting, that would seem to explain why there was a performance decrease when all I changed was whether the data was nested in a object (of an array of objects).  Would it regain its original speed by putting this updateView function as a method of the object instead?  Theoretically that would slice the array of objects, not the object of array of objects?